# How can I cause a post back in an asp.net page with silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

So my solution consists of a website application that has a WCF service and then a silverlight project.

So far I have managed to create the solution such that when a button is pressed on the silverlight app, then the service mentioned above is consumed.

Now eventually, I need to use that service to convert an image to a byte[] array and then do an insertion in an SQL server that is hosted on the same server as the IIS.

However, after this process I need to do a postback to the asp.net page hosting the silverlight application.

I want to change the view on the main asp.net page that the silverlight is being contained in.

Any leads on how to do it?

Edit: including code here

The button on the wcf service has the following code:

```
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client obj = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        obj.DoWorkAsync(result);
```

where result is a byte[] array that I calculate in the silverlight code.

Now the service doWork function for now is:

```
    public void DoWork(byte[] img)
    {
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\users\waqasjafri\desktop\test.txt");
        file.WriteLine("FOR NARNIAAA!");
        file.Close();
    }
```

This was just to test that I can write to a local server. That is not my problem for now. The problem I am having is that this silverlight app is in a asp.net page (called "EmployeeClock.aspx") that has a multiview called "multiView_main". I want the asp.net page to run the following code when the silverlight is done consuming the service.

```
multiView_main.ActiveViewIndex = index;
```

So the problem is how should I go about this. Can I do this by adding something into the code of the service after I write to the file. How do I cause this postback from a silverlight event to the main page. My efforts so far into this makes me think that I still need to use the WCF framework to achieve this.

Hope this elaborates the problem sufficiently.

Comment: Post the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: As Aishvarya wrote, not having your code is quite difficult to guide you.

Comment: I made the edits. Please have another look at the question.